# Is it possible for a reverse proxy to make its request to another proxy and rewrite the urls in the response content?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm currently looking into reverse proxies and don't have a specific one in mind yet.

I am trying to forward my requests from a reverse proxy through another proxy on the web with authentication. The main reason for a reverse proxy is to have the urls rewritten so when the user clicks on it, it will be forwarded through my reverse proxy. However, it also needs to go through an actual proxy with authentication.

So basically what I am trying to achieve is, the user navigates to a site, the request is captured by a reverse proxy, the reverse proxy then makes another request through another proxy (with a proxy authentication). When the reverse proxy gets a response back, it rewrites the urls from the content inside the response and deliver it back to the user.

My question is, is this possible at all? If so, where could I start looking to implement this?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

edit: 
I found a way to rewrite urls in mod proxy using [mod_replace](http://mod-replace.sourceforge.net/docs.html). But still haven't found a way to forward the webrequests through another proxy

Answer (score 1):

This is from Apache's Documentation

## [`ProxyPass` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

> **Description**: Maps remote servers into the local server URL-space
>
> **Syntax**: `ProxyPass [path] !|url [key=value [key=value ...]] [nocanon] [interpolate] [noquery]`
>
> **Context**:  server config, virtual host, directory
>
> **Status**:   Extension
>
> **Module**:   mod_proxy

This directive allows remote servers to be mapped into the space of the local server; the local server does not act as a proxy in the conventional sense, but appears to be a mirror of the remote server. The local server is often called a *reverse proxy* or *gateway*. The *path* is the name of a local virtual path; url is a partial URL for the remote server and cannot include a query string.

> ***Note***: This directive cannot be used within a  context.
>
> The `ProxyRequests` directive should usually be set **off** when using
>   `ProxyPass`.

Suppose the local server has address `http://example.com/;` then

> ProxyPass http://backend.example.com/

will cause a local request for `http://example.com/mirror/foo/bar` to be internally converted into a proxy request to `http://backend.example.com/bar`.

The following alternative syntax is possible, however it can carry a performance penalty when present in very large numbers. The advantage of the below syntax is that it allows for dynamic control via the Balancer Manager interface:

> `ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/`
>
> If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument
>   should also end with a trailing / and vice versa. Otherwise the
>   resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do
>   not deliver the expected results.

The ! directive is useful in situations where you don't want to reverse-proxy a subdirectory, e.g.

> `<Location /mirror/foo/>`
>   `ProxyPass http://backend.example.com/`
>   `</Location>`
>   
>   `<Location /mirror/foo/i>`
>   `ProxyPass !`
>   `</Location>`
>
> `ProxyPass /mirror/foo/i ! ProxyPass /mirror/foo
>   http://backend.example.com`

will proxy all requests to `/mirror/foo` to `backend.example.com` *except* requests made to `/mirror/foo/i`.

> **Ordering ProxyPass Directives**
>
> The configured `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassMatch` rules are checked in the
>   order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins. So usually
>   you should sort conflicting `ProxyPass` rules starting with the longest
>   URLs first. Otherwise later rules for longer URLS will be hidden by
>   any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL. Note that
>   there is some relation with worker sharing. In contrast, only one
>   `ProxyPass` directive can be placed in a `Location` block, and the most
>   specific location will take precedence. For the same reasons
>   exclusions must come *before* the general `ProxyPass` directives.

In Apache HTTP Server 2.1 and later, mod_proxy supports pooled connections to a backend server. Connections created on demand can be retained in a pool for future use. Limits on the pool size and other settings can be coded on the ProxyPass directive using `key=value` parameters, described in the table below.

By default, mod_proxy will allow and retain the maximum number of connections that could be used simultaneously by that web server child process. Use the `max` parameter to reduce the number from the default. Use the `ttl` parameter to set an optional time to live; connections which have been unused for at least `ttl` seconds will be closed. `ttl` can be used to avoid using a connection which is subject to closing because of the backend server's keep-alive timeout.

The pool of connections is maintained per web server child process, and `max` and other settings are not coordinated among all child processes, except when only one child process is allowed by configuration or MPM design.

> **Example**
>
> `ProxyPass /example http://backend.example.com max=20 ttl=120 retry=300`

Comment: Please consider providing a working example. makes your answers better.

Comment: No good, that just sets a HTTP header called Via.  It doesn't send the requests to a HTTP proxy.

Comment: I have edited my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider the answer from @Tim Dunkley, and expand it with the `ProxyRemote` directive. Combining `ProxyPass` and `ProxyRemote` should lead to the requested result, and will be very flexible.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote